# Alternatives for wget giving 'ERROR 403: Forbidden'

Tags: web-scraping, wget, text-mining

I'm trying to get text from multiple Pubmed papers using wget, but seems NCBI website don't allow this. Any alternatives?

```
Bernardos-MacBook-Pro:pangenome_papers_pubmed_result bernardo$ wget -i ./url.txt
--2016-05-04 10:49:34--  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4560400/
Resolving www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov... 130.14.29.110, 2607:f220:41e:4290::110
Connecting to www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov|130.14.29.110|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-05-04 10:49:34 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

--2016-05-04 10:49:34--  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4547177/
Reusing existing connection to www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-05-04 10:49:34 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/why-would-curl-and-wget-result-in-a-403-forbidden

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set custom User Agent like this:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla" http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4560400/
```

Comment: @sherrellbc I assume it's some kind of "bot blocker" plugin on the server, which IMO is a bad idea. Just FYI, I noticed last night that short user-agents like this don't work as well as full, more complete user agents. Not sure how widespread this problem is, but frankly it's annoying for servers to be so picky.

Comment: you can put there any user agent you want, there is some filtering on webserver which "prevents" to crawl

Comment: doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "***ERROR 403: Forbidden***" when trying to download files with *wget* from Github (redirects to s3.amazonaws.com actually). But it only happened when using:

```
wget -N / --timestamping
```

This tries to download a remote file - Only if it is newer than a local copy of the file.

Apparently, the timestamp checking was forbidden by AWS S3. **Removing the -N flag** has solved it.

Note that you can also avoid timestamp checking by using `-O / --output-document=FILE`, or by downloading to a different directory (which does not include the file yet), with `-P / --directory-prefix=PREFIX`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Made sure I have my Mozila browser open and copy/pasted the download url from my Linux virtual machine not from Windows OS. Am not an expert but it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should try enclosing the url link in double quotes, like

```
wget "your_url"
```

Comment: Basically, but not the access problem, here